# Get Form Name, Method Name and More Details that caused the exception

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, error-reporting

I'm trying to catch unhandled exceptions by  using the following code in Program.cs File.

Im trying to create a string containing all the required information of the error.So that i can identify the Point in code where the error occurs.

My question is there a way i can get the following details from the error object **after compilation and obfuscation**

- Name of the form from which the error occurred
- The Line Number of code which triggered the error
- and any other useful info to pinpoint the exact line of code

  ```
  private static void OnUnhandledException(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
      {        
     string error;

            error = e.Exception.Message + "|" + e.Exception.TargetSite;
        }

          private static void OnGuiUnhandedException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
          {


     string error;

            error = e.Exception.Message + "|" + e.Exception.TargetSite;

          }
  ```

Comment: As long as you need this code to work well, you *don't* need obfuscation.  Nobody is interested in decompiling buggy code, other than to diagnose the bug for you.  Which is a lot more common than programmers assume.  So just turn obfuscation off for a simple workaround :)  Contact the obfuscator vendor for support, they all have *some* way to get usable stack traces back.

Comment: @HansPassant Yep you need to tradeoff the feeling of closed code for better error handling.They do offer a method,but it makes vulnerable code more vulnerable

Answer (score 0):

I've written the following snippet and have been using it for all of my apps. It goes through all inner exceptions and stack traces of those exceptions that contain most of the info you need:

```
public static string ExceptionTree(Exception ex)
{
    // find all inner exceptions
    StringBuilder strbException = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        strbException.AppendLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        strbException.AppendLine("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
        strbException.AppendLine();

        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
    while (ex != null);

    return strbException.ToString();
}
```

Comment: UnhandledExceptionEventArgs does not have Stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Just use > System.Environment.StackTrace

```
try
{
    //Exception

    throw new Exception("An error has happened");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     //Open the trace
     System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true);
     //Write out the error information, you could also do this with a string.Format 
     as I will post lower
     Console.WriteLine(trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName);
     Console.WriteLine("Line: " + trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());
     Console.WriteLine("Column: " + trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileColumnNumber());
}
```

Using string.Format

```
String.Format("An error has occurred at {0} at line {1}", trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName,  trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());
```

Comment: UnhandledExceptionEventArgs does not have Stacktrace,will this work?

Comment: @techno http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202987/in-c-sharp-how-to-collect-stack-trace-of-program-crash

Comment: Thanks,but after obfuscation all get is some random characters.But it returns proper data when no stacktrace is used ie: Exception object only. Is there a way to get more data from it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
(e.ExceptionObject as Exception).ToString();
```

solve your purpose.